# Derived equivalences preserved by blow-ups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, blow-ups

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are derived equivalent. Let $\pi : \tilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ be a blow-up of $X$ along a smooth center. Can we find a blow-up $\mu : \tilde{Y} \longrightarrow Y$ along a smooth center in $Y$ such that $\tilde{Y}$ and $\tilde{X}$ are derived equivalent?